# Do I hande this in DAX or SQL?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I've been struggling with a scenario for a while which I want to solve properly. In the image below I've created a model which contains the relevant tables from a more complex data model.

**The requirement**

Calculate this:

DIVIDE

**SUM(Fact_Marketvalue.Marketvalue) x SUM(Fact_Rating.Carbonemission)
where the Fact_Ratings.Carbonemission > 5)**

BY

**SUM(Fact_Rating.Carbonemission)
where the Fact_Ratings.Carbonemission > 5**

The result should by sliceable by Dim_Category, Dim_Customer, Dim_Security and more dimension tables in my model.
Right now I created many-many relationships between Fact_MarketValue and Fact_Ratings on the Security ID, but I want to avoid this relationship. It does compute the correct result, but at query time in the report it is quite slow, and the model becomes complex.

What would be the best thing to do? Create a view in SQL which holds all information needed? Or should I create a bridge table, if so, with what information? Or maybe I am missing some DAX magic..

[image: data model]

I have tried solving this by creating the following DAX Measure. But I am not happy with the many-many relationship. It does compute the correct result but it it is slow and complex in my model.

[image: dax query]

Comment: For the data model I edited the question to show the image directly instead of a link. For the query please provide it as a code block yourself and not as an image.

Comment: This model is going to cause you problems forever because it's not a star schema. In a star schema, there is one fact table only. In SQL, you should generate a single fact table from the three you have. I realize this may seem inefficient because you'll be repeating some data from at least two of the fact tables, but that is the right way. I've had models that went from a couple million rows per table to 70+ million rows after doing what I'm suggesting, and the 70+ million row model was much more performant.

Comment: Improve the model, then do as much calculation in SQL. SQL on a powerfull server performs really faster then PowerBI. This is the way we go. Do not forget to filter unused columns and rows from your model to make it faster and lighter in memory.

Comment: Thanks, does any of you have a basic SQL query example how you would join those two or three fact tables?

Comment: You don't need to join these fact tables into one; star schemas can contain as many fact tables as you need, the idea that you must have only one is wrong. I have a model with 12 fact tables and hundred million records, and it performs perfectly. The real issue is always granularity - if you want to do analysis across multiple fact tables, they must have the same level of details.

Comment: @RADO The fact tables do have the same level of granularity. I agree with your point that a model can have multiple facts. In the case my fact table Fact_Marketvalue has to find records in the Fact_rating by the security_ID, what DAX approach would you go for?

Comment: @Bosmeneer - from the image provided, it does not look like your fact tables have the same granularity (for example, fact rating is only connected to one dimension, while fact Market Value is connected to three dimensions). I think you have mistakes in your data model.

Comment: @RADO The Fact _Rating is indeed not connected to the same dims, the data in there is not about a customer or category. However, it does contain the same level of detail as the other fact tables, which is the security_ID.

Comment: @Bosmeneer - same granularity essentially means that fact tables have the same set of keys. With the current model, your reporting requirements can not be met. You might be able to torture PBI into the desired result with some very ugly hacks, but I hope that's not what you want.